# How can I take an existing function and write it using Func<..> in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I wrote this code:

```
public static bool MyMethod(int someid, params string[] types)
{...}
```

How could I write that using Func?

```
public static Func < int, ?params?, bool > MyMethod = ???
```

Answer (score 8):

The `params` keyword is compiled to an ordinary parameter with the [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx).  You cannot apply an attribute to a generic parameter, so your question is impossible.

Note that you could still use a regular (non-`params`) delegate:

```
Func<int, string[], bool> MyMethodDelegate = MyMethod;
```

---

In order to use the params keyword with a delegate, you'll need to make your own delegate type:

```
public delegate bool MyMethodDelegate(int someid, params string[] types);
```

You could even make it generic:

```
public delegate TResult ParamsFunc<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, params T2[] arg2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, you can't, if you really want to preserve the `params` functionality.

Otherwise, you could settle for:

```
Func<int, string[], bool> MyMethod = (id, types) => { ... }

bool result = MyMethod(id, types);
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm afraid you couldn't do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to declare functions through Func... although you can just  do:

```
public static bool MyMethod(int someid, params string[] types) {...}
public static Func < int,params string[], bool > MyFunc = MyMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Func declaration as such:

```
public static Func<int, string[], bool> MyMethod = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some helper methods like these?

```
public static TResult InvokeWithParams<T, TResult>
(this Func<T[], TResult> func, params T[] args) {
    return func(args);
}

public static TResult InvokeWithParams<T1, T2, TResult>
(this Func<T1, T2[], TResult> func, T1 arg1, params T2[] args2) {
    return func(arg1, args2);
}
```

Obviously, you could implement this for additional generic overloads of `Func` (as well as `Action`, for that matter).

Usage:

```
void TestInvokeWithParams() {
    Func<string[], bool> f = WriteLines;

    int result1 = f.InvokeWithParams("abc", "def", "ghi"); // returns 3
    int result2 = f.InvokeWithParams(null); // returns 0
}

int WriteLines(params string[] lines) {
    if (lines == null)
        return 0;

    foreach (string line in lines)
        Console.WriteLine(line);

    return lines.Length;
}
```